# How do I flag an rpm package that was installed as a dependency to not be removed if the parent package is removed?

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

Some background so this is easier to understand:

I have `cloud-init` installed which installs `libselinux-python` as a dependency. I want to uninstall/remove `cloud-init` without having `libselinux-python` uninstalled as I need this package for other automation like Ansible. How can I ensure this occurs?

Comment: You can run `yum remove --noautoremove cloud-init`